# Arc tangent of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am trying to solve a problem that involves complex number. The original expression is extremely long but after debugging for several hours, I have identified the source of my error. When I do an arc tangent of the expression, with different values for the variable which are extremely close, the value jumps by order of magnitude.

The expression is:
atan(var_z* (0.058659782 - 0.35747651i))*(161669.61 - 26529.028i)

When I use var_z = -20+3.282i, the value I get is 257585.794 - 19514.30i . When I use the value of var_z = -20+3.281i , the value I get is -250313.14 + 63829.09i .

What could be causing this? The expression is not supposed to have any step function. This is causing a big jump/discontinuity in my answer.

I feel like matlab is somehow messing up the atan function. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real parts of the $\arctan$ function values without the factor jump by $\pi$ from $\approx -\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ to $\approx \tfrac{\pi}{2}:$

$$\arctan(( -20+3.281\cdot i)w) = -1.57079037+0.137054543\cdot i$$
$$\arctan(( -20+3.282\cdot i)w) = +1.57079553+.0137053434\cdot i$$

with $w=0.058659782 - 0.35747651\cdot i$.

**Edit:** For the arguments values you have

$$( -20+3.281\cdot i)w = -0.00031521069+7.34199294\cdot i$$
$$( -20+3.282\cdot i)w = +0.00004226582+7.34205160\cdot i$$
which are near the branch cut $\{ti: t\in\mathbb{R}, |t|\ge 1\}$ (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.23.ii), but at opposite sides. Your huge difference is the result of multiplying $\pi$ with
$161669.61 - 26529.028\cdot i$.

The jump is normal, because you use the principal branch of $\arctan$.

Comment: Why is the real part switching signs when the input was reduced by just 0.001i?

Comment: See the edit. $   $

Comment: Thank you! That explains the math. I think I am making some other mistakes in my code.